# Reading a specific line in a .txt file using Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am currently working on an EDI file and now I want to load and read only a specific line on a .txt file and put that in a textbox. Here is what my data would look like

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *01*MKT71          *01*ADEV04         *160331*1001*U*00501*300000001*0*P*>~

GS*IN*MKT71*ADEV04*20160331*1001*300000001*X*005010~

ST*810*300000001~

BIG*20160316*BS13435**NONE~

REF * BM * DHL-2162693540~

REF*CR*5201~
```

Now I want to put only the data DHL-2162693540 located in line number 5 of the .txt file in my Textbox1.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most straightforward way to do this is to read the first however many lines, and only keep the value of the last line read.

Here is some code that accomplishes that:

```
Private Sub ReadLines()

    Dim MyLine As String
    Dim DataLineNumber As Integer
    DataLineNumber = 5

    Open "C:\YourFileNameHere.txt" For Input As DataFile

    Do While Not EOF(1) And LineNumber <= DataLineNumber
        Line Input #DataFile, MyLine
        DataLineNumber = DataLineNumber + 1
    Loop

    Close DataFile

    MsgBox MyLine

End Sub
```

Comment: Having syntax error on this line of code. Line Input DataFile, MyLine

Comment: Oh ok. I thought you were just not caring lol. I'll fix that real quick. Just a side note/tip - you can highlight code in comments by placing backticks around it.

Comment: @HidekiMTC Try placing a single `#` right in front of the variable `DataFile` in that line. I've edited my answer to show what I am referring to, but the newly changed line will look like this: `Line Input #DataFile, MyLine`

Comment: So I manged to get your code working. but what if the information you need is not on the last line? Let's say it's located somewhere in the middle. e.g you want the info on line 5 given that the text file has 10 lines of data

Comment: How do you know what line the desired data is on?

Comment: I've added a variable to make test what line we are on. I made an if statement in the loop which makes sure no more than 6 lines have been read. So if the program is longer than 6 lines, the loop stops after it reads the 6th line.

Comment: Actually  the desired data is really fixed on line number 5. I just want to know how can I extract the data if I need the information on line 5, or line 6 etc.

Comment: Ok, so no matter which line it is fixed on, you can just change the number in the if statement. To extract the data from the line you'll have to split the string containing that line into the good and bad parts. I can help with this, but I'll need more examples of lines containing the data we're looking for. It doesn't matter what the lines 1-4 and 6-whatever look like. But we do need to know either what line 5 looks like, or know exactly how our desired data in line 5 looks like.

Comment: Also, I've edited my code and changed the name of the variable to test the line number, to make it more clear what it is being used for. This also makes it a little cleaner when you want to change the desired line number.

Comment: Ok so I've made a great progress on my project. Also I think you are missing a code to make the `LineNumber` variable to increment. I think from here I will just need to use substring to extract the exact data I want. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: @HidekiMTC Sure, not a problem! If you think that my answer is a good answer for your question, be sure to mark it as the answer so other users will know the solution when they have this problem.